# C# - Parsing ffmpeg standard output when extracting images

Tags: c#, ffmpeg

I am extracting single Video frames by starting a ffmpeg process from my c# code. The default behaviour is to write these images to disk.
However to speed up processing I want to redirect the ffmpeg standard output to receive the stream and process it further in my program.

I am using arguments similar to this:

```
-i \"" + Filename + "\" -vf \"scale=640:-1\" -an -vframes 100 -r 1 -f image2 -
```

This redirects the byte stream to standard output which I can redirect to my program using `process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true`.

This may work fine for movie streams as I only have a singe output, but the call above would produce 10 single images (when writing to hard disk), how can I parse the byte stream from standard output and split it into single files?

Comment: If you know the resolution you should know it by counting the bytes. This is true if uncompressed images are written. If jpg is printed out I have no idea. You would have to try with one,two,three images to check if ffmpeg sends separator between frames.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found a solution which seems to work but strangly enough is not mentioned in the [ffmpeg documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html): Use `image2pipe` as output format.

So for the example above it would be:

```
-i \"" + Filename + "\" -vf \"scale=640:-1\" -an -vframes 100 -r 1 -f image2pipe -
```

This redirects the byte stream to stdout and allows to capture and parse the images

Comment: I posted a related question you may be able to answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11742896/processing-jpgs-stream-from-the-standard-output

Comment: The code really depens on what you want to achieve. For my particular problem I needed the output passed as bytestream which I then parsed with my program. The trick here is that you get one single stream containing all images. You manually have to determine when a new image starts to know which bytes actually represent a single image. This can be done by waiting for the [magic number](http://www.astro.keele.ac.uk/oldusers/rno/Computing/File_magic.html) of the chosen format. If you need additional help post it as a separate question with more details

Comment: @leeprfoog Can you elaborate Magic number, becose the link is broken. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer @leepfrog
This is basically the same:

```
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();

        //Input file path
        str.Append(string.Format(" -i {0}", myinputFile));

        //Set the frame rate
        str.Append(string.Format(" -r {0}", myframeRate);

        //Indicate the output format
        str.Append(" -f image2pipe");

        //Connect the output to the standard output
        str.Append(" pipe:1");



        return str.ToString();
```