# Processing jpgs stream from the standard output

Tags: c#, .net, ffmpeg, stdout

Using FFmpeg I converted a video (mpeg2) into jpgs, redirecting the output into the standard output.

```
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();

    //Input file path
    str.Append(string.Format(" -i {0}", myinputFile));

    //Set the frame rate
    str.Append(string.Format(" -r {0}", myframeRate);

    //Indicate the output format
    str.Append(" -f image2pipe");

    //Connect the output to the standard output
    str.Append(" pipe:1");
    return str.ToString();
```

I'm able to receive the callback from the process with the data:

`_ffmpegProc.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(_ffmpegProc_OutputDataReceived);`

But how can I save that back into jpg files?, I'd need to know the size of each jpg, but I cant figure out how.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't without reading and at least partially understanding the stream structure because JPEG files don't contain e.g. an explicit length indication somewhere at file start.

I see two possibilities that don't involve transcoding:

1. store the intermediate files on disk, but I guess that's just what you want to avoid.
2. try minimally parsing the files - a JPEG file starts with a `SOI` marker (hex FF D8) and ends with an `EOI` marker (hex FF D9).  With a relatively simple state machine you could try splitting the stream of JPG's into separate frames this way.  Now, for robustness sake it's probably better to read the segments individually (see [the JPEG file format](http://class.ee.iastate.edu/ee528/Reading%20material/JPEG_File_Format.pdf) for more info).  You can also study the [ffmpeg mjpeg decoder](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/mjpeg__parser_8c-source.html)'s source implementation, it looks quite robust.

Comment: I suppose (the second option) is the way to go, I'll take a look at those links.

Comment: It's certainly doable and not even that long, the ffmpeg decoder actually reads all the segments which should make detection a whole lot more robust than just by triggering on SOI-EOI

Comment: I'm obtaining some results with the SOI/EOI state machine, but what do you mean with '..ffmpeg decoder actually reads all the segments which should make detection a whole lot more robust..' ?

Comment: Read function find_frame_end in the aforementioned file, you'll see that the code actually "hops" from segment to segment, using the length that's included in each segment.  Because there's no escaping of SOI/EOI these sequences could occur in the datastream, leading to false detections.  Actually reading the segments and using their announced lengths avoids that problem.