# How to can I redirect the image frames of a video outputted by ffmpeg to a python list in a python script?

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I am extracting frames from a CCTV video of certain duration using ffmpeg command. The code written in the python script is as follow:

```py
import subprocess as sp

sp.call('ffmpeg -i c21.avi -ss 00:10:00 -to 00:11:00  op2/frame_%1d.jpg', shell=True).
```

However I want to store every image frames in a python list rather to a file. What are the changes that I need to do?. I have explored opencv cv2.VideoCapture method which resulted in assertion error after processing certain frames of the video.

Comment: Well open the directory including the frames and pass them to a array would be the easiest at this point.

Comment: I am trying to avoid writing the images to a file. Is there a way to do it using ffmpeg command?

Comment: According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10505659/c-sharp-parsing-ffmpeg-standard-output-when-extracting-images) you can make ffmpeg output all the images to its stdout, and you can easily enough retrieve that data with `subprocess`. However, you will still have to parse the binary data to figure out where each image ends and the next begins.